# Cannot install IIS on Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, installation, iis

[image]

I receive error 0x80070057 when trying to install IIS on Windows 10 Home.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Voting to close. The image doens't help as it's not in English. There are too many issues which it could be. And I'm not sure if the question is actually about fixing it or finding out who can fix it. Please [https://superuser.com/posts/1221649/edit](EDIT) your question and provide more detail. When does this happen. Is the Windows 10 version legal. How are you opening it. Do you have permissions?

Comment: error code:0x80070057

Comment: win10 professional can install iis,but the home win10 is not

Comment: The edit link in my first comment is wrong. It should be https://superuser.com/posts/1221649/edit

Comment: Andy, please observe how I have edited your question. The question is much more clear now that it has been changed. When asking questions in the future, please be as clear as you can so that we can quickly understand your problem and get you a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't as I believe you have Windows 10 Home. Windows 10 Home does not come with IIS.

An option may be to use IIS Express. IIS Express does come with Visual Studio.

Or, upgrade to Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: okey I decide to update the system to win10 Pro,thanks